# Insert to foreign key-linked table in django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm writing a rudimentary exercise app in django, with the following table structure:

```
Routine         Exercise         Segment
=====           =====            =====
routine_name    exercise_name    routine_id (fk)
routine_id      exercise_id      exercise_id (fk)
                                 order
                                 duration

* (fk) = foreign key
```

In practice, this looks as follows:

[image]

A Routine contains numerous Segments, and each segment contains one Exercise, the order number (where the segment appears in the routine – first, second, third, etc), and the duration of that segment.

My question is, **is there an way to allow someone to add a new exercise type from the "Add routine" view?** I.e., if I'm making a new routine, I don't necessarily want to have to drop out and go to the Exercise table view to add a new exercise to the list. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Django offer the green plus button to open an add new exercise (or whatever the related model is) by default if the user has add privileges for the related model? I know it does for choice fields in the admin outside of inline contexts.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - I can easily add another *segment*... you can see the big green button in the screenshot. What I want to do here, though, is add another *exercise*. Routine isn't directly linked to exercise, it's routine -> segment -> exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add a ModelAdmin for Exercise.

The obvious consequence of this is that you'll get a "top level" menu option to add exercises. However, a side effect is that everywhere that you have a model with a foreign key to exercise (like in your Segment inline), you'll get a little green "plus" sign next to the Exercise foreign key selector. If you click on that plus, you'll get a popup that will let you create a new Exercise. The popup will have the same layout as the "Add Exercise" page you get if you go through the top level menu, but without the navigation elements.

When you hit "save" on the new Exercise, the foreign key you clicked on will be updated to point at the newly added exercise instance.